# ExtJS: Store with JSON reader store not getting data on load()

Tags: json, extjs

I am feeling absolutely suicidal now after trying everything to get some data in my ExtJS grid along with pagination working fine.

My requirement is something like this: I have to create a grid whose fields (and data) can vary according to user selection. So e.g. if user selects 'Customer' then grid loads with fields: CustomerID, Customer Name, Address, Email and if he selects 'Vehicle' then grid has to load fields: VehicleType, Brand, Model, Price.

The data can be huge and pagination is absolutely required. I don't want to use client side pagination since in case of large data the browser will hang due to memory overhead. Hence I am trying to get the server side pagination.

So I create a model whose fields are populated by data fetched by an AJAX request (*JSON given at the end of the question*) which is fired by the user selection event:

```
var fields = [];
var cols = [];


Ext.onReady(function(){
            var tableModel = Ext.define('TableData', {
                extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
                fields:fields
            });

        var url = "<url>";

 //paging toolbar definition
        var pagingGridToolbar = Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar', {
               store: tableStore,
               displayInfo: true,
               displayMsg: '{0} - {1} of {2}',
               emptyMsg: "No data to display"
        });

 //Grid definition
        var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
                id: "idMyGrid",
                store: tableStore,
                columns:cols,
                height:400,
                width:500,
                filterable: true,
                bbar: pagingGridToolbar,
                renderTo:'panel',               
        });

 //Store definition

        tableStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
                         model: 'TableData',
                         pageSize: 20,
                         proxy: {
                             type: 'ajax',
                             url: url
                         },
                         reader: {
                             type: 'json',
                             root: 'rowdata',
                             totalProperty: 'totalCount'
                             }
                         });


 //Function that is invoked on user selection event.
       function getDataOnUserSelection(userChoice)
            {
                var url;
                Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url : "<url>",
                    params : {
                        userAction: 'getFieldsData',
                        TABLE_NAME: userChoice,
                    },
                    success : function(r){
                        //After this call returns.
                        var res = Ext.decode(r.responseText, true);
                        cols = res.columns;
                        fields= res.fields;

                        grid.columns=cols;
                        tableModel.setFields(fields);
                        grid.reconfigure(tableStore,cols);
                        var dataURL = "<url2 to get the grid data>"
```

(If I use below code then a request is sent to server, grid data is fetched (in form of JSON *given at the end of the question*) and populated in the grid. But since we are using `add` or `load` all the data is sent to grid in one giant block and paging doesn't work.)

```
                        Ext.Ajax.request({
                          url : dataURL,
                          success : function(r){
                            var res = Ext.decode(r.responseText, true);  
                            tableStore.add(res.rowdata);                
                          }
                        });
```

(However if I try to reload the store by updating the url then the same server call is made, same JSON is fetched BUT (and here I want to stab myself!) the data doesn't show up in the grid.)

```
                        tableStore.getProxy().url = dataURL;
                        tableStore.store.load();

                    }
                });
            }
```

As I mentioned `loadData` is loading all the data in one shot, which I don't want since then paging doesn't work.

The JSON for loading fields and columns (from the call to getFieldsData is) :

```
{
    "columns": [
        {
            "dataType": "String",
            "dataIndex": "customerID",
            "header": "customerID"            
        },
        {
            "dataType": "String",
            "dataIndex": "customerName",
            "header": "customerName",

        },
        {
            "dataType": "String",
            "dataIndex": "address",
            "header": "address",

        },
        {
            "dataType": "int",
            "dataIndex": "age",
            "header": "age",

        },
        {
            "dataType": "datefield",
            "dataIndex": "dob",
            "header": "dob",

        }
    ],
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "customerID",
            "type": "String"
        },
        {
            "name": "customerName",
            "type": "String"
        },
        {
            "name": "address",
            "type": "String"
        },
        {
            "name": "age",
            "type": "Int"
        },
        {
            "name": "dob",
            "type": "Date"
        }
    ]
}
```

The JSON for grid data being returned on tableStore.load or tableStore.add is:

```
{
"totalCount": 2,
"rowdata": [
    {            
        "address": "4861",
        "customerID": "50200",         
        "age": "12",
        "dob": "09/03/2002",
        "customerName": "BOISE"
    },
    {
        "address": "4861",
        "customerID": "50200",         
        "age": "12",
        "dob": "09/03/2002",
        "customerName": "AMSTRA"
    }
]
}
```

I have given almost every detail but please let me know if you want to know anything else.

Please tell me what am I doing wrong here. Also if what I am doing is correct/possible or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how your server side code is implemented. But when you are using a store with a page size and calling the store load method such as

```
tableStore.load({
        params: {
            // specify params for the first page load if using paging
            start: 0,
            limit: 3,
            <other request params>
        }
});
```

This ll make a server call with these things as request params.
So you have to write your server implementation in such as way that it returns exatly  3 records i.e the page size along with the totalProperty which is being used to create your paging toolbar.
When you click on the subsequent pages in toolbar it makes another call with these below parameters which you can use at server end to get the specific page data.

- _dc:1418621373690
- page:2
- start:3
- limit:3

Comment: Give Some Example for better understanding

Comment: That's right Sudhanshu. The `page`, `start` and `limit` are getting passed to the server side. Server code is returning a JSON as a result also. The problem is that when using 'load()' then data is not showing in the grid, add() or loadData() do load the data in the grid alright, but then paging doesn't work!